Is there a way to automatically cover a city with isochrones of the same size?
I want to automatically cluster/cover a hole city with isochrones. So that in the next step I can have a closer look at these isochrones. For example, how many people live there. I want all isochrones to have the same size (3 walking minutes) and the whole city to be covered without any isochrones overlapping. I started with openrouteservice and folium, but i did not come that far.
I just tried it manually. But that is way too much work for one hole city. I got to the point that i have isochrones around a point. But there I have to type in all the time, the middel point.
